# How to spyon jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have a chunk of code here that I want to test:

```
var thingId = '#thing-dialog'
if (myObject.isNotAThing) {
    thingId = '#not-a-thing-dialog'
}
$(thingId).dialog({
```

So what I want to do here for my test is assert that `$()` was called with the correct id when the `isNotAThing` property changes on myObject

I've been trying to find a way to setup a spy on this so I can assert that, but not sure how to spy on the `jQuery selector function`.  In my head it would look something like this (although not valid)

```
this.mock$ = spyOn($, '()');
```

so later I could do

```
this.mock$.assertCalledWith('#thing-dialog')
```